# How to select values from a CSV file depending on the value of a specific column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, csv

Take this csv as an example:

```
Col1, Col2
1,3,
0,5,
1,4
0,7
```

Say that I have a list, and I want to append the values of `Col2` to the list only if the value of `Col1` in the same row is `1`. The resulting list should be `[3,4]`.

How can I do this with pandas without using `iterrows()`?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think `.loc` is the most pythonic and simplest method.

   ```
   df.loc[df['Col1'] == '1']['Col2'].to_list()
   ```
2. An alternative using `np.where`:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   df['Col3'] = np.where(df['Col1'] == 1, df['Col2'], '')
   listt = list(filter(None,df['Col3'].to_list()))
   ```
3. `zip` is a loop alternative to `iterrows`.

   ```
   listt = []
   for x, y in zip(df['Col1'], df['Col2']):
       if x == 1:
           listt.append(y)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read in your `csv` into a dataframe named `df`, you could use this:

```
wanted = df.query('Col1 == 1')['Col2'].values
mylist.extend(wanted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

lst_result=[]
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[ind,'Col1'] == 1:
        lst_result.append(df.at(ind,['Col2']))
print(lst_result)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.